# How can I paginate across two tables using Sequel::Model?

Tags: ruby, pagination, sequel

For a change, I'm using a Ramaze, and therefore Sequel, based app instead of a Rails app.

I have a model `Tag` which is many-to-many associated with `:posts` via a join table `:taggings`, and with `:external_posts` via a join table `:external_post_taggings`.

I want to collect both of these associations together, and order them by a date field, which is called `created_at` in each table.

Without pagination, I would do:

```
@combined = (@tag.posts + @tag.external_posts).sort_by(&:created_at).reverse
```

However, I need to use pagination. If it was just .posts I would do:

```
@posts = @tag.posts.paginate(page, 10)
```

but I don't know how to paginate across two tables, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to paginate the combination of tags and posts, you probably want to paginate a union of the two association datasets:

```
@tag.posts_dataset.
  union(@tag.external_posts_dataset).
  order(:created_at.desc).
  paginate(page, 10)
```

However, this has issues unless posts and external_posts use the same model class.  If they use separate model classes, you may have to keep track of the offsets manually for each.  Basically, for each page, select the next 10 records for both associations (starting each at the appropriate offset).  Combine the 2 groups of 10 into an array, sort it by the reversed created_at field, take the first 10 results.  Count the number of posts and external posts in that array of 10 combined/sorted records, and update the offsets of posts and external posts accordingly for use on the next page.

For example, on page 1, you'd use offset 0 for both.  If after combining, sorting, and taking the first 10, there are 7 posts and 3 external posts in the array of 10, on page 2 you would start the posts offset at 7 and the external posts offset at 3.

Comment: Yeah, they are two different model classes.  so i'd have to step through the pages one at a time, keeping track of offsets, till i got to the page i wanted?  yikes, sounds complicated :)  I think you're right though.